# Взаимодействие нескольких клиентов с одним экземпляром COM-сервера

Tags: c#, com, singleton, interop

Здравствуйте.

Просьба не кидаться сразу помидорами, если вопросы дилетантскими покажутся, тем более что не ищу какого-то готового решения, а просто нужен  вектор, куда копать.

В общем, есть сторонняя программа с api на COM объектах, которая поставляется в виде activex dll библиотеки (или по-другому tlb библиотеки, если я не путаю). В этой библиотеке описаны разные классы и что-то вроде корневого Application класса, при создании экземпляра которого запускается стороннее приложение.

Вопросы:

1) Я только разбираюсь с мат. частью, поэтому один глупый вопрос: что в данном случае является com сервером, а что клиентом? Процитирую rsdn:

> Загруженный процесс, в котором создан
> объект, и называется сервером. Процесс
> же, в который передается указатель на
> интерфейс, и из которого будут
> производиться вызовы, называется
> клиентом.

В моем случае экземпляр Application класса я создаю внутри своей отдельной программы и пользуюсь его функциональностью там же. Поэтому возможно данная программа и есть и сервер, и клиент в одном лице. Но, с другой стороны, запускается то самое стороннее приложение, которое тут тоже, возможно, играет какую-то роль

2) И главный вопрос: мне необходимо обеспечить глобальный доступ из разных программ к экземпляру того самого COM Application класса. Если создать новый экземпляр, то будет открыта копия приложения. Мне же нужен некий singleton. Пробовал воспользоваться [ROT таблицей](http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/showthread.php?56079-Get-the-COM-object-for-AutoCAD-2011#post_message_381830), но, как оказалось, приложение в этой самой таблице не зарегистрировано, пробовал сам зарегистрировать, но что-то даже ни одного примера для C# не нашел. Может, еще какие способы есть?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

1) Смотрите. Согласно [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), COM-сервер — это *код*, соответствующий COM-объекту, COM-клиент — это код, пользующийся этим объектом. Это определение не зависит от процессов (так что на RSDN пишут не вполне правильно).

Если код COM-сервера бежит в отдельном процессе, такой код называется outproc-сервером. (Обычно реализуется в отдельном `.exe`.) Если же код сервера бежит в том же процессе, такой код называется inproc-сервером (и обычно размещается в `.dll`, подгружаемой клиентским процессом).

2) Вам, судя по всему, требуется COM-синглтон. такое лучше обеспечить средствами самого COM (вот, например, [статья про это на RSDN](http://rsdn.ru/article/com/dllsingleton.xml)): каждый раз, как кто-то будет запрашивать этот COM-объект, он будет получать всё тот же объект.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, если тема еще не мертва.

1. Доступ к объекту можно получить путем связывания контекста ROT через
   моникеры. Если надо код, подкину.
2. Не советую вешать синглтон, приложение если будет разрастаться начнутся проблемы. Лучше напиши простой COM сервер. И наблюдай за изменением твоего процесса (ведь твое приложение может быть открыто в новом экземпляре или закрыто)